# Postgres ERROR: permission denied for table

Tags: postgresql, psql, rds, pg-dump

I have a dump file generated by using pg_dump from a remote database. I am using the file to restore and populate a database using psql. 
I did not have the user and database name. I peeked into the sql file and figured out the user and database. 
Here are my steps: 
1. psql -h <> -u <> -d ( I used the superuser here).
2. created the user as the application needs to access using this user only. 
3. changed the owner of the database to the user created in step 2 using Pgadmin.

I am unable to access any tables and getting the error -- **ERROR:  permission denied for table**

Please Help !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use dump and restore instead of psql for restoring the database.
e.g

e.g suppose you have database dbname_source in remoteDB and dbname_target in localDB then you can use the below commands for dump and restore

```
./pg_dump -U postgres -p 5432 -h <remote_IP> -Ft dbname_source > dump_of_source.sql.tar 
./pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -d dbname_target dump_of_source.sql.tar
```

Comment: I have no control over the process where they are generating the dump. I am getting just as a .sql file. Peeking into the file I am trying to find the database name and the owner. I then create the user and database and finally use PSQL to import. I missed the owner yesterday and when I added the owner later I started getting the above mentioned error. Really appreciate if you can suggest a solution for my scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Do not create any user and let the script do it. Just create a database different than the one in sql file e.g localdb. And then execute the following command
./psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -d localdb -f mydumpfile.sql

Comment: @ Amjad Shahzad Just clarifying, say my db name is dvd and user who owns is alex ( in source). Following could be the commands:                                                
 `./pg_dump -U alex -p 5432 -h <remote_IP> -Ft dvd> dvd.sql.tar ./pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -d dbname_target dump_of_source.sql.tar  OR ./psql -U postgres -h remote-host -p 5432 -d dvd -f dvd.sql`.  I really don't need the alex user I should use the postgres user. Please confirm Thanks !

Comment: Better to use super user postgres, it will take care of user alex as well. so `./pg_dump -U postgres -p 5432 -h <remote_IP> -Ft dvd > dvd.sql.tar` for dump and  for restoring `./pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -d dbname_target dvd.sql.tar` So when restoring all connection info will be of target dbms on which you want to restore the dump. Assuming you want to restore the dump of database dvd to a local database name as dbname_target.